# Mostrar datos Json con Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, array, json

Cordial Saludo tengo una duda actualmente guardo en mi base de datos un dato de tipo Json como lo muestro en la imagen el dato tiene por nombre **date_table**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde en mi controlador para extraer los datos los hago de esta manera:

```
public function Detalle_serviciosHome(){
    $det_serv = Detalle_servicio::all();
    $detalles = json_decode($det_serv, true);
    dd($detalles);
}
```

y en mi servidor local lo muestra de esa manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que esos datos lo pueda mostrar y los datos de **date_table** mostrarlo en una tabla, Agradezco mucho si me podrían ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

voy a intentar ayudarte.

Daremos por hecho que la vista donde quieres mostrar la información es una plantilla Blade.

Para utilizar la información de la variable **$detalles** en tu plantilla primero debes pasar esa información en forma de una variable a tu vista. Lo primero que debes hacer es declarar una propiedad pública en tu controlador:

```
public $detalles;
```

Ahora debes asignar el valor a esa variable, tu método quedaría así:

```
public function Detalle_serviciosHome(){
   $det_serv = Detalle_servicio::all();
   $detalles = json_decode($det_serv, true);
   $this->detalles = $detalles;
}
```

Lo siguiente seria pasar tu variable a la vista para poder trabajar con los datos, así que en el método de renderización vamos a suponer que la vista es **tabla_detalles** y que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta **components**.

Deberías tener algo así:

```
public function render()
{
    return view('components.tabla_detalles', ["detalles"=>$this->detalles]);
}
```

Una vez tenemos la información en la vista deberíamos crear la tabla haciendo uso de los datos de la variable `$detalles`, incorporando en cada campo la información que proceda.

Ejemplo de la vista ***tabla_detalles***:

```
   <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Modelo</th>
                <th>...</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($detalles as $detalle)
              <tr>
                 <td>{{ $detalle['date_table']['user'] }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $detalle['date_table']['email'] }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $detalle['date_table']['modelo'] }}</td>
                 <td>...</td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Dado que tienes un array con todos los registros del **Detalle_servicio** y en cada uno de estos registros hay array **date_table**, utilizamos un loop foreach para recorrerlo y para extraer esa información utilizamos el acceso a cada propiedad con **$detalle['date_table']['nombre_propiedad']**

Comment: Gracias Por tu ayuda intentare realizarlo tal como me lo planteas